# Should I use "delete $.fn.plugin" to delete a plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, methods, reset, destroy

Any objections for or against the use of `delete $.fn.plugin` (*in combination* with resetting the elements to standard values)?

What's your standard way to destroy a plugin? Are there best practices for that?

Comment: The better plugins have their own `destroy` methods for doing this. Your question is too general to answer -- how a plugin should be destroyed depends entirely on what the plugin does.

Comment: @Blazemonger Yap, i know the question is, "is it a good way to use `delete` in combination with a destroy method"...

Comment: How should we know? We have no idea what your code looks like or what it does.

Comment: @Blazemonger I'm not talking about a specific plugin, rather than about which approaches are popular ;)

Comment: A plugin's `.destroy()` method will destroy instantiated instance(s) of the plugin. `delete $.fn.plugin` will destroy the plugin itself. They are completely different animals.

Comment: What is the goal of destroying the plugin in this case? deleting it will just make anything that calls it throw an error.

Comment: There's no standard way to destroy a jQuery plugin